# Particle convert button makes my particles numbers increase but no conversion

Tags: modeling, particles

I am trying to make a tree by emitting particles from particles. I was planning on emitting twigs from the branches of the tree that I made but I can't convert to an object or emit non-moveable particles from the branches. I need help converting the particles to a mesh/real object.

before...
[image]
after...
[image]

Comment: In official 2.79 after converting Particle system modifier by default continues being on and showing particles afaik so disable or delete it from stack and look up Outliner or in viewport if new objects appeared. In recent builds after converting particles modifier is removed

Comment: What is afaik and stack? How do I delete it? I have only been doing blender for a couple of months.

Comment: "afaik" stands for "as far as I know". By stack I meant Blender's modifier stack. I suggest you watch and read introduction tutorials on Blender, in particular [modifiers interface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html).